# How to know library version?

Tags: 18.04, apt, libraries, versions

Suppose I was told, that `libx265-dev` version should be ≥ 68.

I have

```
$ sudo apt list libx265-dev
Listing... Done
libx265-dev/bionic,now 2.6-3 amd64 [installed]
```

where `2.6-3` looks completely uncomparable with `68`.

How to know if it is greater or not?

---

Here is an example of such a requirement, [`fmpeg` building manual](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu), section `libx265`.

Comment: Can you provide a real-world example?

Comment: @user535733 it is already real

Answer (score 3):

In a terminal enter:

```
apt depends libx265-dev
```

You should see something like:

```
libx265-dev
  Depends: libx265-179 (= 3.2.1-1build1)
  Suggests: libx265-doc
```

The number after `Depends: libx265-` is the version number which should be ≥ 68.

Answer (score 3):

The libx265-dev package is in the default repositories of Ubuntu 16.04 and later (at least until Ubuntu 22.10). In Ubuntu 18.04 open the terminal and type:

```
apt-cache show libx265-dev | grep Depends
```

Results:

```
Depends: libx265-146 (= 2.6-3)
```

`libx265-dev` version in Ubuntu 18.04 is 146 which is ≥ 68.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you require **H.265/HEVC video stream encoder (development files)**
and the libx265-dev_2.6-3_amd64 is the latest stable version.
To make sure you are up to date, open a terminal and type
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libx265-dev`